# Incorrect Syntax near the keyword DECLARE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have answered this sort of in a previous question but now I have another issue. I am trying to create a view and have already been helped in creating the following query;

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
      [Type_ID] INT,
      [Client_ID] VARCHAR(50),
      [PBX_Vendor] VARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT  INTO @table
        SELECT  dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Type_Id, dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Client_Id, dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Description AS PBX_Vendor
            FROM    dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl INNER JOIN
                    dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl ON dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Type_Id = dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Type_Id AND 
                    dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Code_Id = dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Code_Id
            WHERE     (dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Type_Id = 127)

SELECT  [Type_ID],
        [Client_ID],
        (
          SELECT    STUFF((
                            SELECT  ', ' + [PBX_Vendor]
                            FROM    @table
                            WHERE   [Client_ID] = tbl.[Client_ID]
                                    AND [Type_ID] = tbl.[Type_ID]
                            GROUP BY [PBX_Vendor]
                            ORDER BY [PBX_Vendor]
                          FOR
                            XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 1, '')
        ) PBX_Vendor
FROM    @table tbl
GROUP BY [Type_ID],
        [Client_ID]
```

This gives me the results I need and puts the results of columns in the same cell. However when I save the View, I get "Incorrect Syntax near the keyword DECLARE". I nderstand I cant run Declare in a View, so what alternative can I run instead? It must be a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something here, but why don't you do this?

```
WITH ctetable 
     AS (SELECT dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Type_Id, 
                dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Client_Id, 
                dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Description AS PBX_Vendor 
         FROM   dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl 
                INNER JOIN dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl 
                  ON dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Type_Id = 
                     dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Type_Id 
                     AND dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Code_Id = 
                         dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Code_Id 
         WHERE  ( dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Type_Id = 127 )) 
SELECT [Type_ID], 
       [Client_ID], 
       (SELECT Stuff((SELECT ', ' + [PBX_Vendor] 
                      FROM   ctetable 
                      WHERE  [Client_ID] = tbl.[Client_ID] 
                             AND [Type_ID] = tbl.[Type_ID] 
                      GROUP  BY [PBX_Vendor] 
                      ORDER  BY [PBX_Vendor] 
                      FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')) PBX_Vendor 
FROM   ctetable tbl 
GROUP  BY [Type_ID], 
          [Client_ID]
```

You can learn more about CTEs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=SQL.100).aspx).

> ## Using Common Table Expressions
>
> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. A CTE is similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and lasts only for the duration of the query. Unlike a derived table, a CTE can be self-referencing and can be referenced multiple times in the same query.

Comment: @Raddo2003 You're welcome. Please note that if you don't normally include `;` in your queries and you're going to use CTEs more you might want to start. The reason is that the `WITH` keyword must be the first statement in the batch or preceded by `;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare varaibles in views.

> You cannot declare variables in view defiunitions.  You can either
>   create your logic in a procedure or modify your view to make use of
>   the in-built user_name() function in order to return filtered results.

Reference [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/b22350f9-9c9b-42c3-9d36-77d489095ab8)